# How to extend IntoIterator by another trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to define a trait that extends IntoIterator, to achieve something similar to the code bellow, but "associated type defaults are unstable" (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29661).

Is there another way to achieve it?

```rust
pub trait MyTrait : IntoIterator{
    type Item = i32;
    fn foo(&self);
}

pub fn run<M: MyTrait>(my : M){
    my.foo();
    for a in my {
        println!("{}", a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
trait MyTrait: IntoIterator<Item = i32> {
    fn foo(&self);
}
```

This means: everything that implements your trait also implements `IntoIterator` where the `Item` is `i32`. Or put differently: all implementors of `MyTrait` can also be turned into an iterator over `i32`s.

Comment: It worked nicely in the simple example but I got another error when tried to set it in an enum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919186/error-requirements-on-the-impl-of-intoiterator-but-already-implemeted-intoit